# Constraint Layout not working; the layout is destroyed across devices

Tags: java, android, android-layout

[Desired Layout Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhJWp.png)

[Current Layout Photo when tested](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjQvx.png)

Across different devices the layout changes drastically. I have looked around on google for answers but nothing has provided clarity between what is the right way to do things and what is not. What can be done?

Note: There are twenty identical copies of the last image view that are not included in the code below. They are meant to be moved around for graphics.

```
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">
    
    
        <com.example.castbuddyv1.FFVisuals
            android:id="@+id/FFVisuals"
            android:layout_width="389dp"
            android:layout_height="781dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.4"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/rawdata" />
    
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/right2"
            android:layout_width="59dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="84dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="84dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="658dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="29dp"
            app:icon="@drawable/abc_vector_test"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/onoff"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.39" />
    
        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/onoff"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="700dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
            android:rotation="0"
            android:textOff="Motors On"
            android:textOn="Motors Off"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.922" />
    
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/right"
            android:layout_width="59dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="658dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="51dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="51dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="29dp"
            android:rotation="180"
            app:icon="@drawable/abc_vector_test"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/onoff"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />
    
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/statusdisplay"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="166dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="166dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="595dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="183dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="183dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="44dp"
            android:text="Status:"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/onoff"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/depth"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="31dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="49dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="49dp"
            android:text="Depth:"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/rawdata"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/connect"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/connect"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />
    
        <Switch
            android:id="@+id/rawdata"
            android:layout_width="92dp"
            android:layout_height="34dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="692dp"
            android:text="Raw Data"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/connect"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
    
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/connect"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="38dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:text="@string/connect"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/rawdata"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/rawdata"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/depth"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/fish"
            android:layout_width="57dp"
            android:layout_height="33dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="320dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="320dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="87dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/kisspng_computer_icons_symbol_clip_art_5b2bf54c62bee1_4646889015296075004045

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Please add some screenshots so we can see what you mean. It is standard practise to have different layout files for different screen sizes.

Comment: Sure, photos are above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what is this part :

```
<com.example.castbuddyv1.FFVisuals
        android:id="@+id/FFVisuals"
        android:layout_width="389dp"
        android:layout_height="781dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/rawdata" />
```

I'm a beginner, I don't know if this is going to help you, but let's say I want to design your interface, for me I will do this:

1. Making sure to display the interface in vertical by adding below code to `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

   ```
    android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
   ```

   ```
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
   ```
2. Putting vertical and horizontal guidelines in the constraintlayout:

   ```
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
      android:id="@+id/v_guideline1"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="20dp" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
      android:id="@+id/h_guideline1"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="20dp" />
   ```
3. Replacing `(app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="20dp")` with `(app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="x%")` to place it depending on the percentage.

   For example : 30% for the first vertical guideline and 50% for the first
   horizontal guidline :

   ```
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
      android:id="@+id/guideline1"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.3" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
      android:id="@+id/h_guideline1"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />
   ```

This is what I do to make sure that each widget appears in the position I want.

Here how it's look in Android studio:

[Design+Blueprint](https://ibb.co/Tr23yJF)

this is how it looks in : Pixel XL 1440 × 2560: 560dpi:
[Pixel XL](https://ibb.co/RcVwg5m)

this is how it looks in:  Nexus 9 2048×1536:xhdpi24:
[Nexus 9](https://ibb.co/xjJqtfy)

you can see that the screen size changed but the widgets stay in the same position

this is the xml for this interface:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
  android:id="@+id/h_0"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.03" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
  android:id="@+id/h_1"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.1" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
  android:id="@+id/h_2"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.8" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
  android:id="@+id/h_3"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.9" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
  android:id="@+id/h_4"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.97" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
  android:id="@+id/v_0"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.2" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
  android:id="@+id/v_1"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.35" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
  android:id="@+id/v_2"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.65" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
  android:id="@+id/v_3"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.8" />


<TextView
  android:id="@+id/depth"
  android:layout_width="0dp"
  android:layout_height="0dp"
  android:text="Depth:"
  app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/h_0" 
  app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/h_1"
  app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
  app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/v_0" 
  />

<Button
  android:id="@+id/connect"
  android:layout_width="0dp"
  android:layout_height="0dp"
  android:text="@string/connect"
  app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/h_0"
  app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/h_1"
  app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/v_1"
  app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/v_2"
   />

<Switch
  android:id="@+id/rawdata"
  android:layout_width="0dp"
  android:layout_height="0dp"
  android:text="Raw Data"
  app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/h_0"
  app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/h_1"
  app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/v_3"
  app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"  
  />

<Button
  android:id="@+id/right2"
  android:layout_width="0dp"
  android:layout_height="0dp"
  app:icon="@drawable/abc_vector_test"
  app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/h_3"
  app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/h_4"
  app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/v_0"
  app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/v_1"
   />

<ToggleButton
  android:id="@+id/onoff"
  android:layout_width="0dp"
  android:layout_height="0dp"
  android:rotation="0"
  android:textOff="Motors On"
  android:textOn="Motors Off"
  app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/h_3"
  app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/h_4"
  app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/v_1"
  app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/v_2"   
  />

<Button
  android:id="@+id/right"
  android:layout_width="0dp"
  android:layout_height="0dp"
  android:rotation="180"
  app:icon="@drawable/abc_vector_test"
  app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/h_3"
  app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/h_4"
  app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/v_2"
  app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/v_3"      
  />

<TextView
  android:id="@+id/statusdisplay"
  android:layout_width="0dp"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="Status:"
  app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/h_2"
  app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/v_1"
  app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/v_2"             
/>

<ImageView
  android:id="@+id/fish"
  android:layout_width="0dp"
  android:layout_height="0dp"
  app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/h_2"
  app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/h_3"
  app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
  app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/v_0"
   />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

notice that I set the width and height of the widgets to 0dp:

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="0dp"
```

Since the guidelines are set in a percentage, the widgets will be stretch and Shrink according to the size of the screen

you can make the widgets size-fixed by assign dp values for example:

```
android:layout_width="70dp"
android:layout_height="40dp"
```

that all what I got, I hope my explanation is clear and useful.

Comment: Merry Christmas!

Answer (score 0):

You can learn `ConstrainLayout` from [here](https://constraintlayout.com/)

I've try to figure it out the issue with constraint applied in your code. I hope this will help you, please check this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<com.example.castbuddyv1.FFVisuals
    android:id="@+id/FFVisuals"
    android:layout_width="389dp"
    android:layout_height="781dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.4"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/rawdata" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/right2"
    android:layout_width="59dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="29dp"
    app:icon="@drawable/abc_vector_test"
    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@id/onoff"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/onoff" />

<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/onoff"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
    android:rotation="0"
    android:textOff="Motors On"
    android:textOn="Motors Off"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/right"
    android:layout_width="59dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="29dp"
    android:rotation="180"
    app:icon="@drawable/abc_vector_test"
    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@id/onoff"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/onoff" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/statusdisplay"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="44dp"
    android:text="Status:"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/onoff"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/depth"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="31dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:text="Depth:"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/connect" />

<Switch
    android:id="@+id/rawdata"
    android:layout_width="92dp"
    android:layout_height="34dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:text="Raw Data"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/connect"
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="38dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:text="Connect"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/fish"
    android:layout_width="57dp"
    android:layout_height="33dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="87dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```